# Bootstrap getting a link and button on the same line within a list item

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list item which is a link and I'm trying to get a button on the right side of the list item which is also a link. But I want it to be inline Everything worked fine at first then I figured out you can't put an href on any element.

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mMsz.jpg

here's what I got

http://www.bootply.com/okT6tYTYeb#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your demo here : http://www.bootply.com/4444FqAIXA  I put the link inside your span and then added display:inline-block and float:right; to your span